# Input não carrega style disabled

Tags: css

Estou editando alguns `input`, `select` e `textarea`, retirando o estilo "padrão", mas estou tendo um problema. Quando ele está como `disabled`, deveria aparecer com um fundo escuro. Mas ele aparece na cor branca, mesmo estado bloqueado. Alguém sabe o que posso mudar?

### CSS:

```
input, select {
    border: 1px solid #848484; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 30px; 
    border-radius: 30px; 
    outline:0; 
    height:100px; 
    width: 350px; 
    padding-left:10px; 
    padding-right:10px; 
}
```

**Como deveria ficar o fundo:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como está ficando, mesmo disabled:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar assim:

```css
input {
    border: 1px solid #848484; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    outline:0; 
    height:100px; 
    width: 350px; 
    padding-left:10px; 
    padding-right:10px; 
}

input[disabled]{
 background-color: #844;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text" disabled>
```

Desse modo selecionas `input` que tenham um atributo `disabled`.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z95ybuph/